# Eager Load Active Record Association with WHERE on Join Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to perform an eager load but have a where clause on the eager load query.

Let's say we have the following:

```
class Features < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feature_overrides
end

class FeatureOverride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

Where a feature has an `active` attribute, which can be overridden by a feature override.

Feature overrides are added for users, so the `active` attribute on a feature can be overridden by a feature override for a particular user.

Here's the query I have to get all features and eager load the feature_overrides:

```
Features.all.includes(:feature_overrides)
```

With this query I'd still have to search the feature_overrides to see if there exists a feature override for a given user. Adding a where to the eager load doesn't give me what I want:

```
Features.all.includes(:feature_overrides).where('feature_overrides.username = ?', username)
```

This will reduce my result to only include features where there exists an override for `username`.

At this point I think what I want is to do a Left Outer Join, but when I try that active record does not deserialize the feature override association.

I'd like the eager load to somehow perform the queries:

```
SELECT `features`.* FROM `features`
SELECT `feature_overrides`.* FROM `feature_overrides` WHERE `feature_overrides`.`feature_id` IN (...) AND `feature_overrides`.`username` = ?
```

Comment: If you need features which were overwritten by the user, you can do something like this: `FeatureOverride.where(username: username).includes(:feature)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'm actually doing a bit more with the features, I suppose I can get them from that query by doing FeatureOverride.where(username: username).includes(:feature).features, but my situation is a bit more complicated than that...

Comment: Got it, another way is to use `joins` ActiveRecord method. Probably, you can do something like this: `Feature.joins(:feature_overrides).where('feature_overrides.username = ?', username)`.

Comment: This actually still reduces the result by doing an Inner Join :(

Answer (score 0):

So that's sound like you need the Left Outer Join (exactly what you wrote in the question, but my mind was blinded). If you're on **Rails 5** try to use this:

```
Feature.left_outer_joins(:feature_overrides)
```

If you're on **Rails 4** you will need to write this one manually:

```
Feature.joins(%[LEFT OUTER JOIN 'feature_overrides' ON 'feature_overrides'.'feature_id' = 'features'.'id'])
```

You can also append `where` scope if you need to filter `feature_overrides` by the `username`.